# Protected custom settings data are not available for another user in installed managed package

Tags: customsetting, privileges

We have a protected custom setting in a managed package. We installed that package in another developer org and it is working fine. We create one more user with sys admin privileges. When we logged as the newly created user and try to run a vf page which depends on the values from the custom settings does not fetch any data. Why it worked for one user and not working for another user? Please advice.

Comment: What type of custom setting is it? (List or Hierarchy) What does the code look like which retrieves data from this custom setting?

Comment: if a hierarchy setting make sure you have org defaults to fall back on in case the user one does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to turn off the org default and try running the vf page with custom settings to fetch the data.